# NSManagedObjectContext deadlock

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

recently I've run into an issue that I cannot explain. So I have a class DocumentContext which holds a single Document (NSManagedObject) in it. The code for these classes are

```
extension Document {

  @NSManaged var title: String?
  @NSManaged var type: String?
  @NSManaged var created_at: NSDate?
  @NSManaged var fields: NSSet?
  @NSManaged var imagePairs: NSOrderedSet?

}

class DocumentContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

  var document: Document!

  convenience init(document: Document? = nil) {
      self.init(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
      self.parentContext = document?.managedObjectContext ?? NSManagedObject.defaultContext
      self.performBlockAndWait { [unowned self] in
          if let doc = document {
              let id = doc.objectID
              self.document = self.objectWithID(id) as! Document
          } else {
              self.document = Document.create(self)
          }

      }
  }

  override init(concurrencyType ct: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType) {
      super.init(concurrencyType: ct)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

Now here's the weird part, I have two calls on the main thread inside the viewController:

```
    context.performBlock { [unowned self] in
        let pairs = self.context.document.imagePairs?.array as? [ImagePair]
    }
```

And shortly after

```
    context.performBlock { [unowned self] in
        let fields = self.context.document.fields
    }
```

It works as expected, BUT when I change the last call to `performBlockAndWait`, the whole app nicely hangs. I pressed pause and saw that apparently this call `self.context.document.imagePairs?` is blocked by the semaphore, so it appears that it is blocked by the main thread or something. Any ideas why it will do something on the main thread? From my point it should obviously stay in the ManagedObjectContext thread.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - just the second before I pressed post button I realized the answer to my own question )) Will leave it here if anyone will encounter similar problem. The problem was - my parent context was instantiated with MainConcurrencyType. When my code began fetching the relation it was going through this context and therefore the main queue I presume. As soon as I changed the concurrency type to private, the bug's gone.